# How to update tables' structures keeping current data

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# application that uses tables in a SQL Server 2008 database (runs on standalone pc with local SQL Server).

Initially I install database on this pc with some initial data (there are some tables that application uses and the user doesn't touch).

The question is - how can I upgrade this database after user created some new data without harming it (I continue developing on another pc and can add some new tables or stored procedures or add some columns to existing tables).

I mean that when I release new version I bring new version of database on backup file (or anything else?) that holds new structure and those initial tables and I need to upgrade existing database without loosing current data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You need to upgrade your existing database structure using change scripts using commands like `ALTER TABLE` and so on.

There's basically two ways to do this:

- you can use a "diff" based tool like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to determine the differences between your database version x and version (x+1). That tool will create a change script for you, which you can then execute on the target machine to bring your database up to the new structure
- or you can write those change scripts manually and package them up and execute them on the target machine

Either way: you need to keep track of your database versions, and you need to use extreme caution not to cause any data loss with any scripts (like dropping a table or something)

Answer (score 1):

Adding new tables shouldn't hurt existing tables. But when adding columns, you should be careful to fill the values for these columns for existing rows (especially if the columns have a not-null constraint on them - in this case you must use the DEFAULT clause). You can achieve this using the DEFAULT clause and by running a special SQL query after the column is created in order to set the new column's value in existing rows.

Comment: THanks, i do this and on my pc, where i develope the application, i change tables' structures without problems. The problem is to bring all database changes to the user's pc without hurting local data.

Comment: @Leon Changing the database means running some queries like CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE etc, right? So you can run these queries on the user's PC and use the guidelines that I gave you.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I exactly need some template or idea oe to create (automatically??) those CREATE and/or ALTER TABLE queries for all items in the database (also functions and stored procedures and views) to build some command/batch file(?) for upgrading. I don't know tsql well...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Foreign keys to link rows from one table with the rows in another table.  This might help keep your tables smaller and your data more segregated.

Comment: i do have foreign keys where needed, i don't understand how it concerns to copying database strructure?

Comment: @Leon Using foreign keys and smaller tables minimizes the need to add new columns to existing tables.

Comment: i agree :) just development is not finished but we already started atp process on the standalone pc.

Comment: Leon, you keep saying "user's PC".  Are you building a web application (the recommended platform) where there would be 1 database for N users, or are you putting the Database on each user's computer?  Can you clarify?

Comment: No, it's a standalone pc with sqlserver and no development tools and my application running for one user only. A "very" local application :)

Comment: My suggestion is to avoid keeping the DB on the user's computer.  If the database is hosted, all of the problems you're facing go away, plus your application will be built for 2011 and beyond, offering the ability to expand and run anywhere if you need to do this in the future.  Otherwise, you're going to need to bug your user every single time you need to deploy an update.  In my experience, users don't like being bugged.

Comment: ...reality is - standalone pc not connected to any place... therefore i need a copy of database on it!

Answer (score 0):

Really hate doing this without the specifics, but ...

In general:

1. Rename current table to temporary table
2. Create table with new configuration
3. Select from temporary table INTO new table
4. If everything worked, delete temporary table

All this can be done in one script.  I've seen it done.

Alternatively, you might want to consider this:
[SQL Server Management Studio - how to change a field type without dropping table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035295/sql-server-management-studio-how-to-change-a-field-type-without-dropping-table)