# SQL Server Management Studio - how to change a field type without dropping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Server Management Studio, when changing an existing field in design view from `DECIMAL (16,14)` to `DECIMAL (18,14)` it will not allow me to save without dropping the whole table and all its data.

Is it possible to change a field type once a database is populated with records?

Comment: What is `big_decimal`?

Comment: What error do you get when using the designer?

Comment: @Martin Smith bad example sorry.

Comment: @Spark - Ah Ok. Wasn't sure if this was some custom CLR UDT or something.

Comment: +1 @Spark: Edited your question to change `big_decimal` to `decimal`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Just use T-SQL script instead of the visual designer to achieve your goal:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere DECIMAL(18, 14)
```

and you should be fine.

The visual designer takes the extra careful route of creating the table with the new structure and then copying over all the data - it works, but it's tedious. Normally, as long as you don't truncate a column (make it shorter), you can definitely change the column's datatype "in place" using a T-SQL statement.

Also: by default the SSMS designer is extra careful and won't allow any changes that require a drop-and-recreate table cycle. You can disable this extra carefullness in `Tools > Options` and then in this dialog box:

[image]

If you uncheck that option, you will be able to do "destructive" changes in your visual designer

Comment: the table option above will this drop my table? I don't want to lose any data in it just change the field type.

Comment: @Matrin yes just a bad example it's decimal thats all. In HQL I had big_decimal

Comment: So the "prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" option, will this drop my table and its data too? I don't want to lose any data.

Comment: @Spark: unchecking this option allows SSMS to do operations that will need it to re-create the table with the new structure, copy over all your data, and then delete the old table, and rename the temporary table to the name of the table. You will **NOT** loose any data in the process!

Comment: I've turned off that checkbox and made my data type change in designer view, but the procedure times out before it finishes and no changes are made. It is a large table, so I'm interested in changing the type in-place using the script mentioned above. But I'm a complete novice; where would I type those commands?

Comment: I know i'm reviving an old post, but how would you include that it should be Non-nullable?

Comment: @WayneO: in T-SQL code? `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ALTER COLUMN YourColumnNameHere DECIMAL(18, 14) NOT NULL` -- and of course, this will *only* work if you don't have any `NULL`s in your column at the time when you issue this command!

Comment: There are risks with turning off that warning in the designer, one case mentioned by Microsoft is when you use the "Change Tracking feature", but there may be more 
"dangerous" cases, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/ssms/error-when-you-save-table#risk-of-turning-off-the-prevent-saving-changes-that-require-table-re-creation-option

Answer (score 0):

Designer will still drop the table even if the option is unchecked in SSMS. It will just not prompt you next time it does it.  To prove, launch the SQL profiler and alter a column using the SSMS designer and you will see a drop table command issued before the Alter table command is executed.