# Changing the data type without dropping the table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I can change the datatype in sql server 2005 but why cannot in sql server 2008. Everytime if i want to change my datatype i need to drop the table and create again..any alternate solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer:
[SQL Server Management Studio - how to change a field type without dropping table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035295/sql-server-management-studio-how-to-change-a-field-type-without-dropping-table)

> The visual designer takes the extra careful route of creating the table with the new structure and then copying over all the data - it works, but it's tedious. Normally, as long as you don't truncate a column (make it shorter), you can definitely change the column's datatype "in place" using a T-SQL statement.
>
> Also: by default the SSMS designer is extra careful and won't allow any changes that require a drop-and-recreate table cycle. You can disable this extra carefullness in Tools > Options and then in this dialog box:
>   [image]
>
> If you uncheck that option, you will be able to do "destructive" changes in your visual designer